# SharePoint 2013 Survey : User should only see his response but graphical view from all responses

Tags: sharepoint-server, survey, item-level-permissions

In our SharePoint 2013 site we have a survey list. Now the requirement is that the user who has responded to the survey should be able to see only their responses in the '**All responses**' view and should see the graphical summary for all other users' responses.
By selecting '**Read responses that were created by the user**' in the Survey advanced settings we are able to restrict the results on '**All responses**' view page but it is restricting the user from seeing graphical summary page and its not showing anything which is not what we are looking for.
So my questions are:

- How can we set the permission in a way that user who have responded should see only his responses in '**All responses**' page and should be able to see all the responses of all other users in '**Graphical Summary page**'.
- Person who has full control on the survey should be able to see responses of everyone on '**All responses**' and '**Graphical summary page**'.

Friends. I need to filter the view based on 'Created By' column but that column is not present in the view filter drop down. Any idea why is it not there please suggest.Because if I get that column in the filter my issue will be solved.

Comment: Were you finally able to resolve this issue? Or what workaround did you use?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward as long as you have correct group permission inherited or added to this list.

- Go to Survey Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Modify 'Item level permission' like below and click OK.
  [image].
- It by design you don't have to worry.

> **Reference**: [Article](https://www.collaboris.com/sharepoint-survey-permissions-explained/) explains with detailed steps.

Comment: I doubt u read my question. i know the article u r talking about and i even mentioned that in the question. what i m looking for is the user who responded should be able to see only his response in 'View All Responses' view and should see everyone's response in 'Graphical Summary view' which is not hapening with the option u r mentioning its only showing user's response in 'Graphical Summary' as well.

Answer (score 1):

Setting item-level permission “Read responses that were created by the user” will apply to all items in the list, no matter which list view are using. List view is only for displaying items. Thus,  both 'All responses' list view and 'Graphical Summary page' list view will only show items created by current user. It is impossible to make it affects only a specific list view.

You can modify 'All responses' list view and add filter to show all items created by **[Me]**.

1. Open Survey list > switch to 'All responses' list view.
2. Edit the page and edit the web part.
3. Edit the current view.
   [image]
4. Add filter.
   [image]

After that, user will only view his responses in 'All responses' page and he can view all responses in 'Graphical Summary page'. However, it also applies to user who has full control on the list.

Comment: Thanks @JoannaW_SPWX i tried that but for some reason i m not getting 'Created by' field in filtration. Is there any feature or something i need to activate.